# TouchGFX: How handle instructions on pressed/unpressed button

Tags: stm32cubeide, touchgfx

How can I handle a button in TouchGFX that allows me to switch on a LED when it is pressed, and switch off it when  I release the button?
The following code works but it switches the LED on/off every time you touch/untouch the screen...

```
void Screen1View::handleClickEvent(const ClickEvent& event)
{
  if((event.getType() == ClickEvent::PRESSED))
  {

    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LD1_GPIO_Port, LD1_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    HAL_Delay(50);
  }
 if((event.getType() == ClickEvent::RELEASED))
  {
     HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LD1_GPIO_Port, LD1_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
  }
}
```

If I use "flexButtonCallbackHandler(const touchgfx::AbstractButtonContainer& event)" function I can detect if button1, button2, etc were pressed, but I cannot detect if a button was released ...
Any suggest?

Answer (score 0):

The standard `Button` class in TouchGFX only triggers on `clicked`. You can check the source code for `AbstractButton::handleClickEvent()` to see how the code works. `Button` inherits from this class and adds functionality like clicked/released images.

In order to do what you want, you have to create a new class that implements the behavior you want. Checking the source code for `AbstractButton` this should be straight forward to issue a callback for both clicked and released events.